# How are the generalization error and the test set error related? Are they?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, supervised-learning, risk, generalization-error

Let us say that we have a set of input data $x \in X$ with labels $y \in Y$. Given a suitable loss function $R(f(x), y)$, we can define the generalization error of a learnt function $f_{n}$, call it $I[f_{n}]$, as $\int R(f_{n}(x),y) \rho(x,y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$. We say that the model generalizes if $I[f_{n}]$ is approached by the empirical risk $I_{n}[f_{n}] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} R(f_{n}(x), y)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. All this is paraphrased from the Wikipedia page, and makes intuitive sense as well.

In particular, if we pick the $R(f_{n}(x),y)$ to be the $0-1$ loss function, such that $R(f_{n}(x),y) = 1 \iff f_{n}(x) =y$ and $0$ otherwise, then $I_{n}[f_{n}]$ (as far as I can see) is basically the accuracy of $f_{n}$ on some $n$ data points.

Now I also see many places (include reputed papers) refer to the generalization error as the difference between the training error and the test error, for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03530.pdf. I was wondering if there was a concrete connection between these two ideas of generalization. To me both are intuitively correct, but I don't like to believe in intuition :) Maybe there's a way to argue that $I[f_{n}]$ roughly behaves as the training accuracy, and $I_{n}[f_{n}]$ as the test accuracy with $n$ samples with maybe some under/over counting?